# MySQL Server 5.7 failed to start on Fedora Core 24

Tags: mysql, fedora

I have a relatively new install of MySQL 5.7 server on Fedora Core 24 that will not start up.
I had successfully moved the datadir to /data02/mysql/ from the default and started up the database just fine a couple of time, even loaded a 7GB database into it from a mysqldump.
Now I'm getting the below error "Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

The MySQL Error log seems to suggest this is the issue

> 2016-08-27T04:57:06.855134Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>
> 2016-08-27T04:57:06.855195Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
>
> 2016-08-27T04:57:06.855201Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: os_file_get_status() failed on './ibdata1'. Can't determine file permissions
>
> 2016-08-27T04:57:06.855220Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

I have verified that:

1. partition /data02 is read/write
2. chown is set to mysql:mysql recursively on all files in /data02/mysql
3. chmod is set to 755 on /data02/mysql recursively.
   NOTE: I did try 777 and that did not work either
4. pid file and mysql.sock are in locations that should be writeable.

Here's the directory listing showing 777 permissions

```
[root@localhost data02]# ls -al /data02/mysql
total 910768
drwxrwxrwx. 6 mysql mysql      4096 Aug 10 10:35 .
drwxrwxrwx. 6 root  root       4096 Aug 14 03:19 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql        56 Aug  4 03:47 auto.cnf
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1680 Aug  4 03:47 ca-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1075 Aug  4 03:47 ca.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1079 Aug  4 03:47 client-cert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1680 Aug  4 03:47 client-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql    485738 Aug 10 10:35 ib_buffer_pool
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 817889280 Aug 10 10:40 ibdata1
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql  50331648 Aug 10 10:38 ib_logfile0
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql  50331648 Aug 10 10:22 ib_logfile1
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql  12582912 Aug  4 22:38 ibtmp1
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Aug  4 03:47 mysql
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql         7 Aug  4 03:47 mysql_upgrade_info
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Aug  4 03:47 performance_schema
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1680 Aug  4 03:47 private_key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql       452 Aug  4 03:47 public_key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1079 Aug  4 03:47 server-cert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql      1676 Aug  4 03:47 server-key.pem
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mysql mysql     12288 Aug  4 03:47 sys
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Aug  4 22:55 test_tmp
```

Here's the server config

```
[root@localhost data02]# cat /etc/my.cnf.d/community-mysql-server.cnf 
[server]
[mysqld]
datadir=/data02/mysql
socket=/data02/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
```

I'm launching the process as 'root' but it starts up as 'mysql' as it should.
It last worked on Aug 10th.  But was shutdown since then, An OS Patching had been run since then, but that's all to my knowledge.

Here's the startup cmds executed.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL 5.7 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-08-27 04:26:52 UTC; 40s ago
  Process: 5100 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --daemonize --basedir=/usr --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 5066 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5043 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 5.7 database server.
Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL 5.7 database server.
Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 27 04:26:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 5.7 database server.
```